# Como encaminhar o input para outra página?

Tags: html, input

Olá, meu problema é o seguinte, possuo uma pagina feita em php para executar o download, e preciso chama-la no botão(input) já tentei por onclick, porém ao mesmo tempo que chamo a pagina preciso concatenar com uma variável. Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português, talvez queira fazer uma **Tour**: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour ou dar uma olhada na **Central de Ajuda**: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help e verificar como efetuar perguntas de uma forma que sejam respondidas rapidamente, tente informar o que você já tentou e poste o seu código, dificilmente alguém fará o trabalho por você.

Comment: Poste o código que você já tem ! assim é mais fácil respoder.